# OpenShift and Angular deployment on Nginx

Tags: angular, deployment, openshift, angular-routing

I am trying to do a deployment of an Angular 15 app hosted on Nginx on OpenShift with a route like this [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and it works fine but when it's not in root ([www.example.com/myApp](http://www.example.com/myApp)) the app fails to start:

- when I set on index.html  it cannot find any *.js files as the browser seems to try to get them from [www.example.com/vendor_js](http://www.example.com/vendor_js) instead of [www.example.com/myApp/vendor_js](http://www.example.com/myApp/vendor_js)
- when I set  it finds all files but it shows a blank page and in console I get this message for all of the js files: *"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."*

Any idea how to deploy it to a non-root ?

Also worth to mention that I tried setting angular.json with "baseHref" : "/myApp" and to add on providers this line:
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/myApp'}
With or without baseref changes app works fine when I am in root ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) so the "Mime type" error does not make too much sense.